# Usage of complex data types in hive

Tags: hive

It might be a dumb question, What is the usage of complex data types (array of structures/map, map of structures, etc) in the hive . I suspect one of the reasons might be to parse complex JSON objects in hive table. Apart from that, I can think of it might save some space on disk if we use complex data type. Can you please explain example of how it saves data/ how it can speed up queries.